# Range & If Statement using multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have several Sheets involved but I'll have Sheet 2 Active. When I'm on "Sheet 2" I need to know when cell ("C14") becomes active with an IF statement I'm guessing. Once it becomes active, I then need to know if the string in cell ("B2") on Sheet 1 = "Fighter" then I want to insert "some wording regarding the fighter here" in cell ("C14") on Sheet 2. IF it's not "Fighter"then is it "Mage"? If so then insert "some wording regarding the mage here".

This is short hand for example.

if cell C14 on Sheet 2 is active then
check cell B2 on Sheet1. If the text = "Fighter"? Then 
insert "You are brave and use a sword" into cell C14 Sheet2
if it's not equal to Fighter then is it = "Mage"? Then
insert "You cast spells" in cell C14 sheet2
etc..

I need to know how to code this in VBA. I've spent hours searching and trying various code but can't seem to get it right. Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that excel is the best choice of platform for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please only respond with an answer.

Comment: That's not how this site works buddy :P It is possible to do what you are trying to do in Excel using macros but It'd be easier to do it with Access if you only know VBA

Comment: It is possible just need to know the code.

Comment: @user1484182, yes, this is possible, but this site for help of resolving issues with the code, when you are stuck somewhere. try to do it by yourself, and then post your code.

Comment: Sub MyMacro()
         If ActiveCell = ("G14') Then
    if Sheet1.cell ("B2") = "Fighter" Then
    Range ("C14") = "You are a fighter who uses a sword" ElseIf Sheet1.Cell ("B2") = "Mage" Then Range ("C14")= "You use spells."
End If
     End Sub

Comment: I see what you're trying to do; your biggest problem is with what you can use to trigger MyMacro. See the example posted below.

Comment: I was hoping the trigger would be once the cell G14 becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
'The way you check which cell is active is by using an
'Event like this one. This goes into the Sheet2 code module
'which you can get to by right clicking on the sheet's tab and
'selecting View Code.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng_Source As Excel.Range
    Dim rng_Target As Excel.Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Setting the cells that you're interested in as
    'ranges will help minimise typo errors.
    Set rng_Target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C14")
    Set rng_Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

    'Target is a range that specifies the new
    'selection. Check its address against rng_Target
    'which we defined above.
    If Target.Address <> rng_Target.Address Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'If you don't want case sensitivity, convert to upper case.
    If UCase(rng_Source.Value) = "FIGHTER" Then
        rng_Target.Value = "some wording regarding the fighter here"
    ElseIf UCase(rng_Source.Value) = "MAGE" Then
        rng_Target.Value = "You cast spells"
    'You get the idea.
    End If

    ExitPoint:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Clean up
    Set rng_Source = Nothing
    Set rng_Target = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf _
     & Err.Description

    Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

I do agree with the comments that you should always post the code that you've already tried (which you subsequently did), but this is a relatively trivial one and this just clears it out of the way and may be of use to somebody else as well in the future.

Comment: Thanks Alan! You understood completely. However, I'm getting an error "Compile Error" expected end sub.

Comment: Make sure that when you copy the code you're picking up the End Sub riiiiight at the bottom of it (or just type it in). My best guess is that it just didn't copy properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errH
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C14")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If rng1.Value2 = "Mage" Then
                Target.Value = "OMG This is MAGE!!! Run run run away!!!"
            ElseIf rng1.Value2 = "Fighter" Then
                Target.Value = "Fighter? :/ Was hoping for something better"
                MsgBox "Fighter? :/ Was hoping for something better"
                rng1.Value2 = "Mage"
                Target.Value = "Mage. Now This is better ;)"
            Else
                Target.Value = "No, we haven't discussed it."
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
errH:
    MsgBox ("Error number: " & Err.Number & "Description: " & Err.Description)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ZygD - It WORKED! and I'm guessing you're a mage. I must remove the msg box but I think I can handle that. You da Mage Man!